# Python implementation of the Lilly Medchem Rules code?

Tags: software, cheminformatics

As the title suggests, I am looking for a Python implementation of the Lilly filter from the paper: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jm301008n.

The shared code on GitHub (https://github.com/IanAWatson/Lilly-Medchem-Rules) by the paper's authors is in C and C++. I guess because the article was published in 2012 and Python wasn't as popular back then.

I looked for a Python (the language I know) implementation but couldn't find any. Can anyone point me or provide me with a Python implementation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your goal in finding a Python implementation? Is it just to understand better how they implemented these rules? If you want to write a Python script that used these rules, you could just make calls to this existing code.

Comment: I actually need it for a research paper I am writing on an AI-based de novo drug design. The reviewers of a journal requested that I should pass the AI-generated molecules through the Lily filter. I actually want to know how it works as well as use it. So, a Python implementation would facilitate this for me a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at the supplemental information? Between that and the paper, it's not hard to grasp what is going on. Also, python was unleashed to the world in 1991. The code you refer to was written in C/C++ because of speed - the UNIX implementation goes back to at least 1995.

Comment: This is not only borderline off-topic, but may be violating homework policy. Also I suggest learning C++ sooner rather than later.

Comment: C++ is not a requirement, but learning how to use multiple languages in your tool chain is in the modern world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am the primary author of the Lilly Medchem Rules software.

Thanks to all the previous posters who have given really good replies.

Yes, python was not a big thing back when this was developed. This runs on
very large datasets and performace is very important.

The rules can be run as a pipeline from python using subprocess, see
https://github.com/IanAWatson/MedchemRulesPythonPipeline for an
example.

The output format is admittedly horrible, and will be fixed one day.
But doing this in a way that avoids external dependencies is complex.
If all you care about is which molecules pass, just grab the second
column of the output - which is the starting name.

As for running AI generated molecules through the rules, that is
absolutely a good idea, and is being done in many places. But there
is a word of caution. The Lilly Medchem Rules was formulated with
the input from expert Medicinal Chemists over many years. We
implemented rules as problematic molecules were encountered.

Nobody ever encountered something like a 1,4 bridged benzene ring,
c12ccc(C1CN)cc2. That would simply never have occurred. So
that ridiculoous molecule passes through the rules without
complaint - because there is no rule against it.

We could implement a rule to prevent that, but then we get into
a never ending game of whack-a-mole with the AI generators.

There are techniques for dealing with such unprecedented
molecules, and myself and colleagues are working on a publication
to outline some of the things we have done to make AI generated
molecules useful.

But even if a molecule satisifies structural precedent requirements,
it is still important to apply the Lilly Medchem Rules
to drive out precedented, but nevertheless undesirable, molecules.

You should thank your reviewer. Your paper will be better.

If people have questions/suggestions or problems with the software, I am happy to help.

Ian

Comment: Great to have you here, welcome to chem.SE. And thank you for your contribution(s)!

Comment: Thank you very much Ian. This was very helpful.